# What is wrong with this JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript

I do not usually use JavaScript, and cannot see why this is not working. Thanks.

```
function testYear() {
    var dObject = new Date();
    var dRegEx = /^[0-9][0-9]00$/;
    var d = dObject.getFullYear();

    if (d.match(dRegEx) && d % 400 == 0) {
    alert("The year "+d+" is in fact a leap year!");
    //return true;
    }
    else if(!(d.match(dRegEx) && d % 400) && d % 4 == 0) {
    alert("The year "+d+" is in fact a leap year!");
    //return true;
    }
    else {
    alert("The year "+d+" is not a leap year.");
    //return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, I have NO idea if the Regex is correct. Never used them either.

Comment: I expect to see an alert about this year being a leap year when a button is clicked on my webpage; but instead, nothing happens.

Comment: 2011 is not a leap year.  Why would you expect to see an alert saying that it is?

Comment: <input type="button" value="Do the test!" onclick="testYear();"/>

Comment: @PaulTomblin I don't, but to test, I would instead set the value of d to some value that is.

Comment: You are trying to call a `String` method `match` on `d` which is a `Number`. And why are you trying to validate the year as xx00 anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to use a regular expression here. Just use an ordinary integer arithmetic to see if the year is divisible by 100:

```
if (d % 100 === 0 && ...)
```

By the way, if `d % 400 === 0` then it is automatically true that `d % 100 === 0` so the extra test is unnecessary.

---

A year is a [leap year](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Algorithm) in the Gregorian calendar either if it is divisible by 400 or if it is divisible by 4, but not by 100. Try this instead:

```
if ((d % 400 === 0) || (d % 4 === 0 && d % 100 !== 0))
{
    // is leap year
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to match full year against regex, it should be a string:

```
var d = ''+dObject.getFullYear();
```

for instance.

Answer (score 1):

`d` is a number.  You need it to be a string to use the `match` method.  Easiest way to cast it as a string is to add an empty string to it:

```
var d = dObject.getFullYear() + '';
```

By the way, you should look up how to see your JavaScript console because the relevant error would be logged there.  That would greatly aid you in tracking down the problem, or at least pinpointing where the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Forget the regex, it is just the wrong approach here. I can't be bothered figuring out exactly what is wrong when your whole function can be replaced by (almost) a one-liner, but `d` is a number so you can't use `match()` on it. You don't need to test if it is divisible by 100 *and* divisible by 400 - the latter implies the former.

```
function testYear() {
   var year = (new Date()).getFullYear();

   if (year % 400 === 0 || (year % 4 === 0 && year % 100 != 0)) {
      alert("The year " + year + " is in fact a leap year!");
      //return true;
   } else {
      alert("The year "+year+" is not a leap year.");
      //return false;
   }

   // OR, if you don't need the alerts and only care about the
   // return value you can just do this:
   return year % 400 === 0 || (year % 4 === 0 && year % 100 != 0);
}
```